# Is there any way to search for, and then call a method in java from a String?

Tags: java, string, methods, call

I'm asking for if there is a way where I could obtain a string (ie "Foo.bar();" ), and search my jvm for the class Foo and call the static method bar? If so, may you share it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. (I'm going to assume that doesn't help very much. Don't ask questions backwards. You really mean: 'How do you...?')

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), perhaps?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is the tutorial on reflection. But it seems like you'd also need a parser. That is a whole different subject on expression languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is using Java reflection:

```
try {
    Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("Foo");
    Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("bar");
    Object retObject = myMethod.invoke(null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle errors here...
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is if `bar()` is a static method here, and if it has no parameter.

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect) for more information on reflection.

Comment: @Leo: Same here... to me this actually seem to answer the question.